# How do I get ffmpeg to encode all files in one directory to another directory? My directory names and filenames all have spaces and periods in them

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, basename

I am using the Terminal on a Mac.

Per another question, I am doing

```
for i in ./01.\ Original\ Recording/*.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 64k ./02.\ Compressed/"$(basename $i)"; done
```

(as you can see, there are spaces in the directory names as well as in the filenames)

The output files are being put in the right directory (`02.\ Compressed`).

Unfortunately, they come out named as `01.?Original?<Filename?With?Space>.m4a` (first part of directory name and rest of file name with spaces substituted by `?`)

Comment: Btw.: Use quotes. Replace `basename $i` with `basename "$i"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the right combination of quotes worked.

```
for i in ./01.\ Original\ Recording/*.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -b:a 64k 02.\ Compressed/"$(basename "$i")"; done
```

That's quotes around the `$(basename ...)` as well as around the `$i`.

I initially though the inner quotes needed to be escaped - `\"$i\"` -  but that did not work and proved unnecessary